# Find out how long until sleep mode?

Tags: vb.net, windows

I'm working on a program and I need to find out how long time until the computer will go into sleep mode.

I have no clue how to do this. I also googled and searched here on Stack Overflow but couldn't find anything.

Comment: [TimeRemaining member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), Pinvoke required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what does Pinvoke mean? Kinda new to this.

Comment: Put this on the shelf until you've read and thoroughly understood the google hits you get when you query "what is pinvoke?"

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/powrprof.callntpowerinformation

Comment: Thanks that might be helpful :)